# Custom button that inherits from button in xaml has does not exist in namespace error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, namespaces

The weird thing is, it does exist and it can find it as the xaml compiles fine.

It's defined in the user control like so:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:myResources"
```

The whenever a new button is added like so:

```
 <local:KeyboardButton
```

It says the name keyboardbutton does not exist in the namespace myResources all the classes for the keyboard button are in that namespace, so I'm out of ideas, any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should write also your assembly name.. smth like:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:myResources;assembly=myResources"
```